# undefined procedure on ECLiPSe 7.0 Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the next .ecl file:

```
:-lib(ic).

test(Valparaiso, Olmue):-
    Valparaiso :: 1..10,
    Olmue :: 1..10,

    2*Valparaiso + 1*Olmue #<= 10,
    1*Valparaiso + 2*Olmue #<= 8,

    labeling(Valparaiso),
    labeling(Olmue).
```

So I get the next error:

> calling an undefined procedure 2 * A + 1 * B #<= 10 in module eclipse

I use ECLiPSe 7.0 for run that script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's something Prolog/ECLiPSe beginners occasionally stumble over: The "less-equal" sign is `=<`, not `<=` as in many other languages.  Best remembered by visualizing the shape of the operator:

[image]

It's actually more beautiful, isn't it?  As to why it was done this way, folklore says that one wanted to reserve the `<=` as a left arrow or reverse implication symbol.